# Three-way duel without a terminator?

Tags: probability, game-theory

### Background

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687272/a-three-way-duel-probability-puzzle), the three way dual has a terminator whose has 100% percent of hitting the target, things simplify much because that terminator will let the tree-way duel to two-way duel very quickly.

Now if that guy don't have one hundred percent accuracy, what is the strategy that A will take?

### Here is the complete description of the current question, you can ignore the above discussion and start from here directly.

$A,B$ and $C$ arrange a three-way duel, $A$ can hit target with accuracy $1/4$, while $B$ can hit with accuracy $1/2$, $C$ can hit with accuracy $3/4$. They shoot in turn, that is $ABCABC\cdots$ until two of them are down. Since $A$ is first to shoot, what is $A$'s strategy that have the largest chance to win? Suppose $B$ and $C$ are also reasonable man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If he has to shoot it's better to kill C. Whoever he kills the other will shoot at him, so better B shoot at him than C.

But if he is allowed not to shoot, then we can calculate is it better to wait (cos we know B and C will not shoot at A)

So probability for A to survive **when refuse to shoot** is:($h$ and $m$ mean hit/miss, $D_{AB}$ means probability for A to survive duel AB when A shoots first) $P=B_hD_{AB}+B_mC_hD_{AC}+B_mC_mP$
$$D_{AB}=1/4(1+\frac 3 4 \frac 1 2+(\frac 3 4 \frac 1 2)^2+(\frac 3 4 \frac 1 2)^3+...)=2/5$$
$$D_{AC}=1/4(1+\frac 3 4 \frac 1 4+(\frac 3 4 \frac 1 4)^2+(\frac 3 4 \frac 1 4)^3+...)=4/13$$
So
$$P=\frac 1 2 \frac 2 5+\frac 1 2 \frac 3 4 \frac 4 {13}+\frac 1 2 \frac 1 4P$$
$$\frac 7 8P=1/5+3/26=41/130$$
$$P=164/455$$
And lets calculate probability **if he decide to shoot**: $$P=A_hD_{BA}+A_m(B_hD_{AB}+B_mC_hD_{AC}+B_mC_mP)$$
$$P=\frac 1 4\frac 1 2\frac 2 5+\frac 3 4(\frac 1 2 \frac 2 5+\frac 1 2 \frac 3 4 \frac 4 {13}+\frac 1 2 \frac 1 4P)$$
$$\frac {29}{32}P=1/5+9/104$$
$$\frac {29}{32}P=149/520$$
$$P=596/1885$$

First is slightly better than second, so he should wait(if is allowed to do so)

Comment: Your formula turn the dual three to dual two. Very nice. It will take me some time to check it!

Comment: Do you think if I lower again $C$'s accuracy(larger than $B$'s though), say $3/4 \to 5/8$ so that shooting in the air may not be $A$'s best strategy?

Comment: If A and B are 1/4 and 1/2 then no. If B starts the duel, A has 1/5 chances, if A starts he has 2/5 chances. So if A waits it is 1/2*2/5+1/2*$D_{AC}$ still better then 1/5

Comment: Will it be generalized that as long as  $P_A< P_B<P_C$, best strategy for $A$ is to wait?

Comment: If p(A)->0 and p(B)->p(A) and p(C)->1, then isn't really matter who starts duel between A and B. It is only matter to kill C. In that case, if A shoots, p=p(A)/2+p(A)/2+p(A) and if doesn't it will be p=p(A)/2+p(A). So he better shoot