# Three Way Duel - Probibility Puzzle

Tags: probability

I came across this website trying to learn how to solve a three-way duel puzzle.. While I did find a similar version of this question had been asked, trying to rework it was not at all successful so I am hoping somebody can talk me through this version (very explicitly!)

It is as follows:

Archer, Brian and Chris have an argument and decide to fight a three-way duel to settle the matter.
The rules of the competition are as follows:
They will take turns to fire. As Archer hits his target only 50% of the time, he will have the first shot. Being more reliable with a 75% strike rate Brian will go second, and as the best shot, scoring 90% of the time Chris will go third.
The survivors will continue to take their shots in this order until only one of them is left. Assume that any hit results in death.
Assuming that each of them applies the strategy that will give them the best chance of winning, the probability (correct to three decimal places) that Archer is the ultimate winner =0.AAA, and the probability that Caesar wins = 0.CCC

I need to find the value of AAA, and CCC and apply them to the 2nd part of the puzzle.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is Archer allowed to deliberately miss his first shot?

Comment: Yes, he can miss the first shot.

Comment: Have you learned modelling by markov chains ? It's the ideal tool here.

Comment: Duplicate (with different probabilities) of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/687272).

Comment: Is it ordered shooting or first guy can shoot anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I re-read the question and considered the strategy of each duelist as well as remembered the law of large numbers (as Dominik rightly pointed out!). This is my working for the probability of Archer winning.

We first consider the strategy of Archer, Brian, and Chris. Their strike rates are respectively $P(A)=0.50, P(B)=0.75, P(C)=0.90$. Based on the strike rates, and assuming the strike rates are known to the duelists, it stands to reason that both Archer and Brian will shoot Chris, while Chris will shoot Brian.

We now consider the result where Archer wins the three-way duel. There are three possible scenarios with this result, i.e. (1) Chris hits Brian, Archer hits Chris; (2) Archer hits Chris, Archer hits Brian; (3) Brian hits Chris, Archer hits Brian.

Consider Scenario (1). A possible sequence of events for Archer hitting Chris with the $n$-th shot is shown in the following table, where the table entries are interpreted as follows: C' in the A row and #1 column indicates that Archer's first shot missed Chris.

```
   #1 #2 #3 ... #n-1 #n
A  C'  C' C'...  C'  C
B  C' 
C  B
```

The probability of this sequence occurring is
$$\begin{align*}
P(Seq_1)&=0.50^{n-1}\times 0.50\times 0.25\times 0.90\\
&= 0.50^n\times 0.25\times 0.90  
\end{align*}$$

Now in the above sequence Chris hits Brian on the first shot. The following table shows the sequence if Chris hits Brian in the second shot.

```
   #1 #2 #3 ... #n-1 #n 
A  C'  C' C'...   C'  C
B  C'  C' 
C  B'  B
```

The probability of this sequence occurring is
$$\begin{align*}
P(Seq_2)&=0.50^{n-1}\times 0.50\times 0.25^2\times 0.90\times 0.10\\ 
&= 0.50^n\times 0.25^2\times 0.90\times 0.10
\end{align*}$$
Generally, the sequences are of the form

```
   #1 #2 #3 ... #n-2 #n-1 #n
A  C'  C' C'...   C'  C'  C
B  C'  C' C'...   C' 
C  B'  B' B'...   B
```

The probability of the sequence occurring is
$$\begin{align*}
P(Seq_n)&=0.50^{n-1}\times 0.50\times 0.25^{n-2}\times 0.90\times 0.10^{n-3}\\
&=  0.50^{n}\times 0.25^{n-2}\times 0.90\times 0.10^{n-3}
\end{align*}$$

The overall probability of Scenario (1) occurring is thus the sum of the probabilities of all possible sequences in this scenario:

$$\begin{align*}
P(S_1)&= \sum_{i=1}^n P(Seq_i)\\
&= 0.90\times 0.25\times \frac{1}{2^n}(1 + 0.25\times 0.10 + \cdots + (0.25\times 0.10)^{n-3})\\
&= \frac{9}{40}\cdot\frac{1}{2^n} (1+0.025+ \cdots +0.025^{n-3})\\
\end{align*}$$.

In the limit $n\to\infty$ we have
$$\begin{align*}
P(S_1)&= \frac{9}{40}\times \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac{1}{2^n}\right)\times \frac{1}{1-0.025}=0\\
\end{align*}$$

Similar analysis for Scenarios (2) and (3) give $P(S_2)=20/79$ and $P(S_3)=15/79$. Hence the probability of Archer winning is
$$
P(A)=\sum_{i=1}^3 P(S_i)= 0 + \frac{20}{79} + \frac{15}{79}=\frac{35}{79}
$$

Comment: @JimmyK4542, there is no possibility of Archer hitting on the first try as that would imply that his hit rate would be 100%.

Comment: I believe in the senario, he would shoot, but choose to shoot at nothing. It is implied that they do whatever they can to stay alive the longest. Shooting the ground or into the air would be his best course of action I believe...?

Comment: This is a highly wrong interpretation of probabilities. What you have calculated is the *expected* number of tries. But there is no guarantee that $A$ will hit in the second shot. This is like saying that in two flips of a fair coin, one of the flips is guaranteed to be heads.

Comment: Fair enough, I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: OK.. it is clear to me that this problem is way above my ability level! Thank you for trying to explain it though!! I actually need to answer to the probability of A winning, and the probability of C - would it be too much to ask for you to let me know the probability of C also because I've tried for hours to rework the problem but can't get anywhere..